# Is there an analogue of uniform continuity for multivariable functions? And, is addition and multiplication uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, uniform-continuity

I know the definition of uniform continuity for single variable functions from the reals to the reals. Is there an analogue of that definition for multivariable functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $n \geq 2$? And with that definition, is it possible to prove that the addition function $f(x,y)=x+y$ is uniformly continuous over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, whereas the multiplication function $g(x,y)=x \times y$ is not uniformly continuous over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Uniform continuity makes perfect sense in the setting of a general metric space. I do not understand what multiplication function you have in mind on $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^n$; if you mean the dot (scalar) product, then writing it with $\times$ is iconoclastic, indeed.

Comment: Notions of analisis have roots in the concept of *neighborhood*, the set of points which is less than a certain distance from another. In $\mathbb{R}$ an $\epsilon$  neighborhood of $x_0$ would be the set of points $x$ such that $|x - x_0| < \epsilon$. Can you think of a way to translate this notion to $\mathbb{R}^2$?  $\mathbb{R}^3$? $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Given metric spaces $(X,d), (Y,\varrho)$ we call $f : X \to Y$ uniformly continuous if $$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \delta >0 \forall x_1,x_2 \in X : d(x_1,x_2) < \delta \implies \varrho (f(x_1),f(x_2)) < \varepsilon$$. Or in other words, it holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ regardless of $n$ value coupled with suitable metric mapping to another metric space via some $f$.

Comment: @TedShifrin By multiplication function, I mean the function that takes an ordered pair of real numbers and returns their product, i.e, $xy$.